# Make hunspell work with emacs and german language

Tags: emacs, spell-checking, hunspell

I want to make `hunspell` work with emacs24 and a german dictionary on a ubuntu 13.04-box.

To do so I installed `hunspell` and `hunspell-de` and added the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-dictionary "deutsch8")
```

When I open a file in emacs and start `flyspell-buffer` I get `Starting new Ispell process [[hunspell::deutsch8]]` but it blocks the emacs buffer (mouse becomes a rotating disk indicating to wait) and works for endless without showing any results. So there must be something wrong with my config.

Without the second line it works, but only for english texts.

So what's the best way to setup `hunspell` for `emacs24` with a german dictionary on ubuntu 13.04? Are there any possible pitfalls?

Comment: Note that the dictonary names are different for hunspell compared to ispell. Instead of `(setq ispell-dictionary "deutsch8")`, you should use `(setq ispell-dictionary "de_DE")`. Note, however, that this requires emacs 24.4 or greater. For earlier versions you need add the definitions to `ispell-local-dictionary-alist` as provided in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with Emacs 24.4, the ispell package supports Hunspell and its dictionaries out-of-the-box.  Therefore, adding the following two lines to the init-file should be enough to set Hunspell as the default spell-checker and German as the default spell-checking language.

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell"
      ispell-dictionary   "de_DE")
```

---

For Emacs versions before 24.4, proceed with the following.

To check if the dictionary is listed in the path run `hunspell -D`.
It should output something along those lines:

```
...
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US
/usr/share/hunspell/de_BE
/usr/share/hunspell/de_LU
/usr/share/hunspell/de_DE
...
```

Next, add your preferred dictionaries to `ispell-local-dictionary-alist` in your `.emacs` file

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("deutsch-hunspell"
                                              "[[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[']"
                                              t
                                              ("-d" "de_DE"); Dictionary file name
                                              nil
                                              iso-8859-1))

(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("english-hunspell"
                                              "[[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[']"
                                              t
                                              ("-d" "en_US")
                                              nil
                                              iso-8859-1))

(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell"          ; Use hunspell to correct mistakes
      ispell-dictionary   "deutsch-hunspell") ; Default dictionary to use
```

In addition to that you can define a function to switch between the german and english dictionaries and bind it to `C-c d` for example

```
(defun switch-dictionary-de-en ()
  "Switch german and english dictionaries."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((dict ispell-current-dictionary)
         (new (if (string= dict "deutsch-hunspell") "english-hunspell"
                   "deutsch-hunspell")))
    (ispell-change-dictionary new)
    (message "Switched dictionary from %s to %s" dict new)))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c d") 'switch-dictionary-de-en)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think you should add a `(require 'ispell)` before the `(add-to-list 'ispell-local...)` line.

Comment: I think it will not hurt if I add a little comment for those  Windows users who might fall on this. In Windows Emacs has the `LANG` environment variable set to the regional settings. It is a good idea to add something like `(setenv "LANG" "en_US")` to your init file. This will be your initial dictionary, unless you change it. The default `LANG` value might be set to something possibly weird (say `ENG`), generating an ispell/hunspell error.

Comment: @antonio True, but in my case, `(setenv "DICTIONARY" "en_GB")` worked.

Comment: The creation of custom dictionary entries for hunspell is not required for emacs > 24.

Answer (score 0):

From https://passingcuriosity.com/2017/emacs-hunspell-and-dictionaries/

> Add
>
> ```
> ;; Set $DICPATH to "$HOME/Library/Spelling" for hunspell.
> (setenv
>   "DICPATH"
>   "/path/to/hunspell/dictionary")
> ;; Tell ispell-mode to use hunspell.
> (setq
>   ispell-program-name
>   "hunspell")
> ```
>
> into your `~/.emacs`.

My dictionary files were at `/usr/share/hunspell`.